# Do concurrency issues in kernel happen when using single core processor?

Tags: concurrency, linux-kernel, multicore

When a kernel is compiled on a multicore system, there will be multiple threads or processes operating simultaneously. So, concurrency problem will be an issue.

However, when there is only one core in the processor. will it still be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Imagine that your worst enemy has total control of the scheduler and can make the processor switch from one thread to another thread at the worst possible time.

Comment: Sure, and besides that, interrupts may happen at almost any time, which adds to the concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is not to do with number of processor, in-fact it was made to have an effect of multiple processor with one core.
But one thing, in singe core its not truly concurrent, only an illusion.
If you mean that way, yes, true concurrency is not possible with single core.

Comment: Concurrency is not same as parallelism. Two jobs are concurrent if they are not serially executed. In time sharing stem preemptions cause concurrency for example.